# How to create a PowerShell script to check if txt files have more than 1 row of text?

Tags: windows, powershell

So I have alot of .txt files. I need for it to move txt files to a certain folder if they have more than 1 line.  That is,

```
Text text text
Blah blah blah
```

But leave it alone if it's just

```
Text text text
```

Any suggestions on how to do this? This is on Windows XP if that helps.  Thanks!

EDIT: Thanks John for your efforts. Figured out a way to do it in PowerShell

```
# Specify folder name that will contain the filtered .txt files
$goodFolder = "Filtered"

get-childitem *.txt | foreach ($_) {
$a = get-Content $_.fullname | Measure-Object

# If more than one line is found in text file, move it. Otherwise, leave it alone
If ($a.Count -gt 1) {   # If there is more than one line found in txt file
    Move-Item $_.fullname $goodFolder       # Then move it to a folder with text files with more than 1 line
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Note: the original question was how do this in a .bat file.

This answer is a solution to the original question. It is *not* a powershell solution.

save this as clines.bat

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set clines = 0
for /F %%J in (%1) do set /A clines = !clines! + 1
if %clines% LEQ 1 goto finis

rem @echo %1 has %clines% lines
move %1 %2

:finis
endlocal
```

and then call it in another batch file that iterates through the files

```
@echo off
for %%I in (*.txt) do call clines.bat %%I newfolder
```

Comment: Awesome, works perfectly! Thanks a ton, however you might want to edit your code and change "mov" to "move" :) Thanks again!

Comment: Well at least for me changing "mov" to "move" worked for me.  Dunno if this is because I'm on WinXP?

Comment: Hmm actually, I'm getting some strange results. Like sometimes there are files that still remain with more than 1 line of text. I know that's kind of vague... Any ideas?

Comment: no, move is correct, I had that line commented out when I tested the script.

Comment: I think the for /F loop may only count non-blank lines, could that be it?

Comment: It could also be that the files need CR LF and not just LF as line terminators.  I don't really know.

Comment: I was running it on about 500 text files, it did move alot of text files with more than 1 line, but there were still text files remaining that also had more than 1 line of text (non-blank).  Is that what you were asking?

Comment: How would I add the CR LF line terminator?

Comment: I'm saying a file with 1 line of text and 1 blank line might not move. a file that had LF's as line separators might not be seen by the for loop as having on a single (long) line. CR LF is the standard for windows. If you open the file in notepad, does it look like 1 long line?

Comment: I don't think it's moving a file with 1 line of text and 1 blank line. But it's sometimes not moving a file with more than 1 line of text (and it shows in notepad, like 5 lines of text)

Comment: post the text and Ill try it on my machine.

Comment: John, thanks for the help and your time.  No need anymore though, I figured out how to write it in PowerShell.  I posted the original code in my question if anyone needs it.

Comment: using powershell is cheating ;).  Seriously, if plan to allow other tools you really should say so in your question.